# Android create a template for library module

Tags: java, android, templates, module

So i have been playing around with android templates i managed to create template for my list activity with adapter and holder and the model class itself it saved me a lot of time. I shifted my work strategy lately to modularization each feature in its own module and things got better performance wise build speed and debugging wise. Now here is the thing every time i want to create a feature i end up creating a new module with the initial skeleton that i work with, this is taking me time, so i wanted to develop a template which has the type of a library module where i only declare the name of the module and the language and it will generate my skeleton where i will declare in the recipe.xml.ftl and export them in the global. Now all the online tut  are only on the level of activity like listActivity but none according to my search help in creating a library module.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm chasing this for months now (not very actively), but still don't have a proper solution. 1st of all, I'd like to confirm a couple of things. 1- that you're using `build.gradle` instead of `build.gradle.kts`. And second, double checking that your code belongs to a single project / git repository. One way is making a gradle settings plugin (not one that adds tasks, one that configures the settings). Along the lines of `class HelperPlugin : Plugin<Settings>`. Otherwise, see https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/sharing-gradle-configuration-in-multi-module-android-projects-370602f526a7

Comment: One more promising link https://discuss.gradle.org/t/plugins-and-apply-from-in-the-kotlin-dsl/28662/8. Pls share if it works for you.